# Could not load the image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier (again)

Tags: ios, xcode, image, ipad, bundle

(Xcode 6.0.1, iOS 7.1.1, iPad2)

- Added three new images to Images.xcassets
- Checked "Copy items if needed" on import dialog
- Build phases -> Copy Bundle Resources:  Deleted and re-added Images.xcassets
- Checked image names to avoid case sensitivity issues
- Cleaned and rebuilt.
- Quit Xcode and restarted
- Deleted app from device for clean install

Trying to set the image as a button background.

Images are showing in the simulator, but not on a device. This leads me to believe that they're not being bundled with the app, despite the fact that I've included images.xcassets in the build.

I would like to check and see if the three new image sets are included, but there does not seem to be a way to drill down into images.xcassets within the "Copy Bundle Resources" branch under "Build Settings."

I am setting the image background in storyboard by clicking on the image view, selecting the "Attributes Inspector" button, and then selecting the image name in the drop-down under "Background."

Other images work; it's just the newly added images that don't show up.

I'm stumped... any advice?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## It was dots in the file name!

The new images were named with dates appended to the end of the filename, using dots to separate month, day and year; like so:

- puppy.10.17.2014.png
- kitten.10.17.2014.png
- chick.10.17.2014.png

I stripped out the dots, and named the files like so:

- puppy.png
- kitten.png
- chick.png

What a headache... I hope this helps someone out there in cyberspace!

Answer (score 11):

In my case the problem was that I used some .JPG images (which I know is not the ideal format but I wasn't worried with that yet since I was only doing some initial development).

I converted one of the images to .PNG (using Preview), imported and the problem was resolved!

Comment: Lifesaver comment for me!

Answer (score 1):

drop a uiimageview and assign any one of these image to it to verify it shows on device or not.

Comment: It wasn't the answer, but it helped me to debug the issue.